# Uniform float in fragment shader. Tablet PC

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader, uniform

I am using JNI and NDK to build an OpenGL project, everything is ok on my phone (galaxy nexus), but i've tried to start this app on several tablet pcs (huawei and acer) and find a strange behaviour:

in my fragment shader there is a value:

```
    uniform float current;
    ...
    gl_FragColor = (...,current);
```

in my code i do:

```
    g_currentAreaLoc = glGetUniformLocation(g_nGLESProgram, "current" );
    ...
    glUseProgram(g_nGLESProgram);
    glUniform1f(g_currentAreaLoc, area);
```

When i try this code on the phone everything is perfect but on tablets there is no expecting results.

**BUT** if i hadcode for example **0.0** instead of current - ***everything is ok on this tablet.***

I can't figure out why this variable works on phone and there are troubles on tablets (maybe depends on OS version).

Comment: Do you have proper compile/link error checking? How about glGetError?

Comment: I'll check it now - but this code works on the phone =(

Comment: That's pretty much irrelevant. Just cause some piece of code works on one opengl implementation doesn't mean it will work on all. You should always do proper error handling and testing on multiple platforms.

Comment: Yes you are right, but glGetError always return 0. Maybe some trouble of using variable in shader...

Comment: I think it happens because shader needs to have float variable as 0.0 (with dot) and when i pass the variable smth strange happens :(

Comment: even  glUniform1f(g_currentAreaLoc, 0.0f); fails, only "current = 0.0" works